# Multiple NIC and Docker containers

Tags: linux, networking, docker, containers

I'm trying to solve specific problem regarding Docker containers and routing.

A Docker host is running several network interfaces (3G USB modems), each having internet access. So, in short;

eth0 - WAN IP 1
ppp0 - WAN IP 2
ppp1 - WAN IP 3
ppp2 - WAN IP 4

How to specify which NIC each container should use if I want container to use a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I ahed very similar issue. Unfortunately I had to use VirtualBox for this to work properly.

I have used Vagrant to create VirtualBox Virtual Machine and provisioned it with Ansible and then changed default route of that VM. Something like this:

`route add default gw IP2`

That would mean creating 4 different VM's but thats how I would approach the problem.

Comment: Why not set the route within the containers itself?

Comment: Yeah, that's something I'm trying to avoid since I'm pretty tight on server resources (good ol' server with only one core and 3GB of RAM) and I need only specific app running multiple times.

Comment: It does not demand more resources to put a route into a container instead of the host. Does it?!

Comment: @Auzias - I was responding to VirtualBox solution. Regarding your answer, it is impossible to add a route to container since NIC interfaces from host are not reachable inside of container?! 7732135373dd:/# route add default gw 10.209.198.237 -> SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

Comment: Sounds obvious indeed, but how can you assert that each container is using a different gateway?

Comment: Anyway, found a workaround for this. Since my application can use proxy I installed squid on host machine and used tcp_outgoing_address directive to route squid on different interfaces. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: It is not possible to set other route inside running container as whole networking would be dealt with through `docker0` interface. Unless you set up another bridge with other routing table. That might work but I have never made it work properly.